# Cron command not working, but works in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I have an extremely simple cronjob that I set up to make sure a script keeps running, and email me if it goes down (low tech, I know, but it was intended as a quick fix)

Unfortunately, this cronjob isn't doing its job

Here is the relevant line from my crontab:

```
* * * * * pgrep -f app.py || echo "Your app is down" | mail -s "URGENT" steven.abarnett@gmail.com
```

When I run the command in shell, it works: I receive an email only if the app is down. As a minor side effect, when the app **is** running, it outputs the PID to the screen.

When I run the command via a cronjob, I never get any emails. Investigating (by setting up the `MAILTO=` parameter to see the cronjob output) I noticed that when the app is running, it outputs **two** PIDs, and when the app is not running it outputs one PID (never zero, so it never sends an email)

It's almost as if the cronjob is spinning up a process which is, in turn, being seen by itself -- much like how typing `ps -ax | grep "anything"` will always return:

```
12345 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto anything
```

Does anyone know how to fix this cronjob?

Comment: I suspect your hunch is correct - cron is probably naming the process - have you tried using MAILTO to see the output of `pgrep -f app.py`? You can use `grep -v "grep"` to eliminate grep (or pgrep) from the output.

Comment: AFAIK crontab just starts programs, it is not a shell. Have you tried to put your big command in a script and make that script the target of the cron entry?

Comment: `grep -v "grep"` was the solution. I'm not 100% familiar with the implementation details of cron, but it seems `pgrep -f` doesn't work. I guess it runs the "bash" process (or similar) with arguments for the command you want to execute? Regardless, that got it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, the solution was fairly simple:

When running

```
pgrep -f "anything"
```

in a cronjob, it will return a process for the bash shell spawned by cron.

Instead I had to use

```
ps -ax | grep "anything" | grep -v grep
```

to search for the running process and simultaneously remove any process which had "grep" in the name

Comment: this was SO ANNOYING. The main reason I used pgrep in the first place was so it wouldn't return itself in the results.